# Won't create a PostgreSQL database on Unix server

Tags: django, postgresql, unix

I am trying to deploy my django project to a unix server. When I run the command to create the PostgreSQL database using SSH, I encounter the following error:

```
$ createdb elections
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Does the error mean running 'locally' as in the server or my machine?
What is stopping it from connecting to the server?
How do I fix the error?

Comment: Are you already running a PostgreSQL server? And if so, can you connect to it using any other tools (i.e. pgAdmin)? The error message looks like it is trying (and failing) to connect to a pg database server.

Comment: @AndrewLively I'm pretty sure PostgreSQL is installed on the server but I don't think any PostgreSQL software is running. This is my first time doing anything like this and I don't really know what I'm doing...

Comment: `pg_ctl start` if you have cluster. if not - `initdb` and then `pg_ctl start` - after that should allow